# REQUEST_DENIED when using Google Maps AutoComplete

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am unable to use Google Maps AutoComplete. I have read all the articles about this problem, and I still get REQUEST_DENIED:

The following services are turned ON:

- Google Maps API v3
- Places API
- Prediction API

Simple API Access:

- API key: **
- Referers: Any referer allowed
- Activated on: (A few days ago)
- Activated by: ** – you

I have even activated my credit card (don't know if that makes a difference for traffic under the quota):

The following happens (tested both from a browser and command line cURL):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=New&types=(cities)&key=$apikey

{
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)

Required parameters

```
input — The text string on which to search. The Place service will return candidate matches based on this string and order results based on their perceived relevance. 
sensor — Indicates whether or not the Place request came from a device using a location sensor (e.g. a GPS) to determine the location sent in this request. This value must be either true or false.
key — Your application's API key. This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management. Visit the APIs Console to select an API Project and obtain your key. Maps API for Business customers must use the API project created for them as part of their Places for Business purchase.
```

I don't see "sensor" in your example request.

Comment: sensor=true|false was indeed missing from my request. Thanks to you and damnation to Google for generic error messages. Does anyone know why the sensor parameter is paramount to generating these results, by the way?